# Multiple Ring Buffer returns RuntimeError: ERROR 000824: The tool is not licensed

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, python-script-tool, license, error-000824

I'm creating a tool that will be used by the Geoprocessing widget on my organisation's enterprise server. When I attempt to run my tool, I get an exception:

> ERROR 000824: The tool is not licensed

The tool in question is covered by the basic license - so I'm unsure what is causing this exception.

Here is the code that I am using:

```
import arcpy
def ScriptTool(featureSet, outputName, distances):
    # Script execution code goes here
    
    # To allow overwriting outputs change overwriteOutput option to True.
    arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
    arcpy.ImportToolbox(r"c:\program files\arcgis\pro\Resources\ArcToolbox\toolboxes\Analysis Tools.tbx")
    # Process: Multiple Ring Buffer (Multiple Ring Buffer) (analysis)
    arcpy.analysis.MultipleRingBuffer(Input_Features=featureSet,
                                      Output_Feature_class=f"{arcpy.env.scratchWorkspace}\{outputName}",
                                      Distances=distances,
                                      Buffer_Unit="Meters",
                                      Field_Name="distance",
                                      Dissolve_Option="NONE",
                                      Outside_Polygons_Only="FULL",
                                      Method="PLANAR")
    return
    
    tempBuffer()
# This is used to execute code if the file was run but not imported
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Tool parameter accessed with GetParameter or GetParameterAsText
    featureSet = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) #param type: feature set
    outputName = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1) #param type: string
    distances = arcpy.GetParameter(2) #param type: long (list)
    
    
    ScriptTool(featureSet, outputName, distances)
    
    # Update derived parameter values using arcpy.SetParameter() or arcpy.SetParameterAsText()
```

Here is a screenshot of the parameters I have set up for my tool:

[image: Tool Parameters (See script comments for further ref)]

Comment: Are you signed in if you open ArcGIS Pro?

Comment: Yes, signed into to ArcGIS Enterprise, and the same problem reoccurs when signed into the ArcGIS online portal.

Comment: I've also tried changing the tool to run arcpy.MultipleRingBuffer_analysis() instead of arcpy.analysis.MultipleRingBuffer() but still receive the same error.

Comment: Make sure ArcGIS Pro is open and logged in. Is Pro saying you're licensed or is it prompting you to log into the site where your licenses is hosted (agol or portal)? Also, remove the line with "arcpy.ImportToolbox" in it and try again. That's not needed.